# ruby closure issue (cannot access var)

Tags: ruby

```
class SomeClass
end

some_local_var = 5

sc = SomeClass.new

def sc.should_work_closure
  puts some_local_var # how can I access "some_local_var", # doesn't this work like a closure ?
end

sc.should_work_closure()
```

Line 9:in `should_work_closure': undefined local variable or method`some_local_var' for # (NameError)
    from t.rb:12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `def` does not work like a closure.

To make `sc` available in the `def` you could make it a constant, make it global (usually a bad idea) or use `define_method` with a block (which are closures).

However since you're not inside a class and `define_method` is a method for classes (and modules), you can't just use it. You have to use `class_eval` on the eigenclass of `sc` to get inside the class.

Example:

```
class <<sc; self end.class_eval
  define_method(:should_work_closure)
    puts some_local_var
  end
end
```

This will work, but it looks a bit scary. It usually is a bad idea to access local variables from the surrounding scope in method definitions.

Comment: in 1.9.2 you can simply go: `sc.define_singleton_method(:should_work_closure) { puts some_local_var }1

Comment: It does look scary, but it is most certainly not "usually is a bad idea to access local variables from the surrounding scope in method definitions". That's a super common thing to do in functional programming.

Comment: @JohnSalvatier You're comparing apples with oranges. Ruby does not have nested method definitions, so when we're talking about "local variables from the surrounding scope", we're talking about local variables at the global scope. So we're basically talking about mutable (because if they weren't meant to be mutable, they'd be defined as constants, which *can* be accessed from within a method) global variables. Those aren't very common in functional programming at all.

Comment: I did not realize ruby doesn't have nested functions.